# Rails, Could not find gem

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rubygems

I have strange problem which say this "Could not find 'rspec-support' (~> 3.4.0) - did find: [rspec-support-3.3.0] (Gem::LoadError)". Yes I understand that problem is wrong gem version, but i need to use 3.3.0 version. For now i tried these options. 
Uninstall gem on several ways:

```
gem uninstall rspec-support
```

and select last option to delete all

```
gem uninstall rspec-support -v 3.4.1
gem uninstall rspec-support --version '~> 3.4.0'
gem cleanup
```

But nothing helped, dependency still contains reference to 3.4.0 version.
Thank you for your attention, I  hope that someone can help

Comment: I expect another gem you are using is requiring the `~> 3.4.0` version of rspec-support. You need to look through the other gems you are using, find the one with that requirement, and see if there is an earlier version of that gem that will work with the version of rspec-support you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for your help, other my colleagues use same application ( with same gem file without problem) so based on yours words i focus my mind on test app, where several of gems use rails-support ver. 3.4.1 as dependency. Try to remove specific gem, but without success. So for now, I used command `bundle clean --force` to remove all gems installed for test app and it's finally works. Again thanks for your help